# ArcGIS Attribute table add field and summarize certain categories?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table

I try to summarize CorineLandCover12-classes together to a higher level into a new column.

For example: 1.1.1 continous urban fabric plus 1.1.2 discontinous urban fabric should become 1.1 Urban fabric in a new column.

I added the new column but got no clue how to add an query as an VB script.

Can it be something like this:

If 'code12' = 111 or 'code12' = 112
then "name it" '1.1' or "no input as I have to do the same with other landuse classes"

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour), also, please edit your question with more information. It is unclear what you mean by "I added the new column but got no clue how to add an query as an VB script."  and unclear as to what your actual issue is.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this the following way,

- Query by attribute for Continuous and Discontinuous
- Then create a new column 'Urban Fabric'
- finally with the field calculator enter in '1.1' for the entire column

Answer (score 1):

I would add a new column to your attribute table and make it text and give it a name like LandUse or something.  Then using field calculator and vbs to  make something like this, which will calculate the new field.

Pre-Logic Script Code:

```
dim result

if [Code12] = "111" then
     result = "1.1"

Elseif [Code12]  = "112" then
     result = "1.1"
Elseif [Code12] = "113" then
     result = "1.3"
Else result = "0"

end if

Landuse = result
```

I am not sure your exact logic you are using to calculate the new field values, if you would need a double if-then etc,  but this is the basic framework on how to do it.  If you need further help you will beed to give a little more information :)